# Thumbnail shell extension .NET

Tags: c#, windows, shell, interop, pinvoke

Does anybody know working thumbnail shell extension written in C# that works on winXP? Also if that doesn't exists does anybody know how to implement IExtractImage interface and all needed structs in C#? Thanks in advance.

NOTE: It can be done using using .NET 4 and all in one code framework provides samples for it but there is no samples for preVista oses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a tutorial on using the pre-vista thumbnail extension interface, IExtractImage.  It's pretty difficult if you start from scratch.  I only recommend this if you understand all the issues surrounding shell extensions in managed code.

http://blog.walkingtarget.com/2018/02/as-far-back-as-windows-2000-microsoft.html

Answer (score 3):

The official line is that shell extensions should not be written in managed code.

For example, see what [Raymond](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx) has to say. Or the official line from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758089%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It's still possible to write the extension itself in C++ and use IPC to do the generation itself in a .net helper process.

Comment: Wow I see the point of Raymond, but I also remember to have seen some articles of Dino Esposito about programming shell extensions in .NET, he actually wrote a book and he is a skilled guy ! wonder where the truth is...

Comment: @CodeInChaos Yes the point is you don't want it as an in-proc server. People also forget that shell extensions don't just run inside Explorer, they run inside every app that shows a common dialog. If you get them wrong you can really make a mess of someone's machine!

Comment: @Davide Of course it can be done, and you'll often get away with it, perhaps for a long time, but then someone will have two conflicting extensions in one host and it's game over!

Comment: As of .Net 4.0, this is no longer true.

Comment: @SLaks There seems to be a distinct lack of clarity on that point. I find conflicting opinions. Do you know of any official statement from MS? I've linked to what appears to be an up-to-date article on MSDN backup up my assertion. Of course, it's perfectly possible that you are right and the MSDN article is not! It would be helpful to anyone reading this if you could give us a definitive link.

Comment: social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/7ce0c480-59e3-4732-a608-1974a908e44a/ says that is suported and All in one code framework provides samples which are suported by Microsoft.